# Isometry between two planes(differential geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

The following exercise problem is contained in O'neill's text. 
[image]

(a) is directly derived from the computations with the definition of the isometry.

However, there is something wrong in (b).

To determine $F$, we need to get $T$,$C$. ($T$:translation part, $C$:orthogonal part).

As $C$ depends on the choice of frame(the sort of basis), $T$ is not determined uniquely.

I think this is not good problem. Am I right?

Comment: why do you expect to get unique solution? Translation is not unique unless you have more conditions.

Comment: @user26977/ Then, there are several isometries for (b) as I asked?

Comment: yes, you always can add translation parallel to your final plane that does not change anything

Comment: @user26977/ Thank you :)

Comment: @user26977/ Is the orthogonal part not unique too?